# How High and Low frequency filters effect activation in the next layer?

Tags: deep-learning, convolutional-neural-networks

Generally, we come across terms such as High Frequency and Low frequency filters in Convolutional Neural Networks (CNN). In regards to this highlighted statement, in 'S1' section of [this](http://yosinski.com/media/papers/Yosinski__2015__ICML_DL__Understanding_Neural_Networks_Through_Deep_Visualization__.pdf) paper by Jason Yosinski (ref 1), [image] I thought, in order for high and low-frequency filters to produce a similar effect, weight of low-frequency filters should be greater than high-frequency filters. I would like to understand why I am wrong and I will be grateful if anyone can elaborate about High and Low frequency filters in CNN, in general, or in this context. Thank you.

Ref 1: Yosinski, Jason, et al. "Understanding neural networks through deep visualization." arXiv preprint arXiv:1506.06579 (2015).